# How to get records from MongoDB only based on date in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to get records from MongoDB based on the start date and end date in C# ignoring time?

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b63b03dbcd1238b4567"),
    status: 1004,
    comment: "Rem dolor ipsam placeat omnis non. Aspernatur nobis qui nisi similique.",
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:34:59.804Z")
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b66b03dbcd1238b4568"),
    status: 1001,
    comment: "Sint et eos vero ipsa voluptatem harum. Hic unde voluptatibus et blanditiis quod modi.",
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-06T11:35:02.814Z")
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b66b03dbcd1238b4569"),
    status: 1001,
    comment: "Sint et eos vero ipsa voluptatem harum. Hic unde voluptatibus et blanditiis quod modi.",
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-07T11:35:02.814Z")
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b66b03dbcd1238b4570"),
    status: 1001,
    comment: "Sint et eos vero ipsa voluptatem harum. Hic unde voluptatibus et blanditiis quod modi.",
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-08T11:35:02.814Z")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make the following range query:

```
// start date, inclusive
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// end date, exclusive
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 05, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var dateQuery = new BsonDocument
{
  { "created_at", new BsonDocument { 
    { "$gte", fromDate },
    { "$lt", toDate }
  } }
};

var result = collection.Find(dateQuery).ToList();
```